# Confused about request path being sent to my Express server from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, web

I have a basic setup for Node.js Express server

I am trying to serve html files using `res.sendFile`, using this route handler:

```
router.get('/:run_id/:test_num',function(req,res,next){

    var runId = req.params.run_id;
    var testNum = req.params.test_num;

    res.sendFile(path.resolve('results',runId,testNum),{
        maxAge:'58h'
    });

});
```

in my app.js file, I have this middleware

```
app.use('/results', require('./routes/results'));
```

the problem is that the request is being routed like so:

```
  pathname: '/results/results/1450830953375/test6.txt',
  path: '/results/results/1450830953375/test6.txt',
  href: '/results/results/1450830953375/test6.txt'
```

so the problem is that it is `/results/results/` instead of just `/results`

I am using RequireJS and the module that contains the data of the files to be request looks like this:

```
    define('SumanTestFiles',function(){
            return new Object(["results/1450830340344/test5.txt","results/1450830340344/test6.txt"]);
     });
```

and then I loop over each file path and request it from the server using jQuery/AJAX:

```
define(['SumanTestFiles'],function(stf){

    stf.forEach(function (testPath) {
        $.get(testPath).done(function (msg) {...
```

so you can see that the testPaths have not been tampered with, they without a doubt simply "results/1450830340344/test5.txt", or the like.

so my question is, why does the path show up on my server with two adjacent 'results' string instances in the path?

It does not make a lot of sense, because the request should just be

> /results/1450830953375/test6.txt

not

> /results/results/1450830953375/test6.txt

anyone have any ideas? thanks

Comment: Where are you logging the request path?

Comment: thanks, it's logging on the server, the server output is the 3 lines above (pathname,path,href)

Comment: I believe if you change `path.resolve('results',runId,testNum)` to just `path.resolve(runId, testNum)` that might work. It's trying to resolve the path `/results/runId/testNum` but you have already routed `/results` already. Not 100% sure though hence why this is a comment.

Comment: thanks, working on it, this is a really weird one

Comment: Ok I figured it out, will post an answer or delete the question depending on how useful it is

Comment: I think AJAX is adding the front-end URL path to the request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new to me, since I fairly new to web development

The short answer is that instead of this:

```
  define('SumanTestFiles',function(){
            return new Object(["results/1450830340344/test5.txt","results/1450830340344/test6.txt"]);
     });
```

I need to do this

```
  define('SumanTestFiles',function(){
            return new Object(["/results/1450830340344/test5.txt","/results/1450830340344/test6.txt"]);
     });
```

otherwise the AJAX request path to my server will be relative to the URL in the searchbar, instead of absolute. Holy crap that was confusing.

Comment: Nice work and +1. Since I have nothing better to do, I would like to point out that passing an array to a constructor invocation of Object does absolutely nothing. The constructor will return the array itself without copying it so you may as well remove the constructor call entirely.

Comment: thanks, I do the "new Object" thing only for syntax highlighting in my IDE :) I think the new Object constructor is basically a no-op if the argument is already an object type, so you're right, I might remove the new Object call